# Dissolve has one county outline

Tags: qgis, dissolve

I'm new to QGIS and I'm trying to create a statewide map using specific regions, which break down by county. The steps I'm using are:

1. Vector Geometry: Fix geometries
2. Vector Geometry: Delete holes
3. Vector Geoprocessing tools: Dissolve by region

This works, but one county still has an outline on the map, even when the region map is the only layer (though if I check the attribute table, it is combined with its region).

In the attribute table, `Shape_Leng`, `Shape_Le_1`, and `Shape_Area` are all `0` for only this county, so I'm guessing this may be part of the issue. Is this likely the cause of the problem? And if so, how can I fix it? I got the shapefile from the SOS of the state and I don't have any other source.

Comment: it's probably a topology error, check the topology for gap/overlap and fix any

Comment: It seems that the rouge county has some topology issue.
Try either fixing geometries also after dissolving, or deleting holes again.

Comment: The values in the attribute table are just static values in a table. They have nothing to do with the actual geometry of the feature.

Comment: Deleting holes after dissolving fixed it - thanks!

Comment: Can you post your solution as answer in case someone else has the same question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running [Vector Geometry: Delete holes](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#delete-holes) after dissolving fixed the issue